# sftp vs ssh public/private key (beginner)

Tags: security, ssh, terminal, sftp

I'm given my public key to a server and now I have the ability to connect to it via sftp in nautilus. Is there a way for me to use those same credentials to ssh to the server through terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Add your public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and that should do it (most of the times, depends on server settings).

Comment: I've been trying to connect and getting a 'Permission denied (publickey).' error. This would fix that?

Comment: Correct way: http://codept.blogspot.com/2006/11/permission-denied-publickey.html ; Easy way: move your private/public key outside your ~/.ssh/ and it should prompt your password (assuming it used to before you generate your key)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for setting up the password-less ssh authentication:

http://manjeetdahiya.com/2011/03/03/passwordless-ssh-login/